# query data undefined in node.js mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

i'm trying to get data from database but new update `result.ops` not working in mongoDB version 3.0 it works what is new way to fix this code because in console i am getting undefined

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient

const connecetionURL = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017'  
const databaseName = 'task-manager'

MongoClient.connect(connecetionURL, { useNewUrlParser: true }, (error, client) => {
    if(error){
        return console.log('Unable to connect to database!')
    }
    const db = client.db(databaseName)

     db.collection('users').insertOne({
         name: 'vano',
         age: 12
     }, (error, result) => {
         if(error){
             return console.log('Unable to insert user!')
         }

         console.log(result.ops)
     })
})
```

i should get in console { name: "vano", age: 12} something like this but i am getting undefined

this is 3.0 doc but i am writing now in 4.0
[https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#~insertOneWriteOpResult](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#%7EinsertOneWriteOpResult)

Comment: could you log `result` ?

Comment: @mohammadNaimi yes and logging something like this {
  acknowledged: true,
  insertedId: new ObjectId("6133d4264da50b5bc95d4e36")
}

Comment: its ok when you insert in mongodb it returns object like you logged

Comment: @mohammadNaimi yes but i want to logged my data what i inserted in 3.0 you can do it but why they deleted that option

Comment: beacuse I think its not important , you know what you are inserting :)
and another thing in big object if mongo return whole of object it will take network and more process cost

Comment: no iam saving db in my folder so dont need time but i need new way to know how to use callback result correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use db.collection("exmaple")
      .findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: "-1" },
        { $set: {
         name: 'vano',
         age: 12
        } },
        { returnOriginal: true ,upsert:true}
      )
```

use `findOneAndUpdate` with `upsert:true` to insert if not exists
and use `returnOriginal: true` to return inserted data
just in finn query write a query didn't match any time for example `{ _id: "-1" }`